# Getting rid of Terminal tabs

Tags: macos, terminal, tabs

Until today, when I opened a new Terminal window, it had only one bar, the kind of window bar all windows have, with at the left the red/yellow/green disk-shaped buttons for close/minimize/maximize. But now I keep getting a second bar, the tab bar, with a + button for "open new tab" at the right. I must accidentally have changed some setting. I prefer the old, tabless windows. How can I undo this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for:

View >> Show Tab Bar

It has a menu accelerator shortcut of ⇧⌘T

Comment: Thanks. ⇧⌘T also works as a toggle. That solved the problem.